# "ValueError: too many values to unpack" (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm getting this error when I try to click the button on my python project, it should return a list of the average points scored per game using a package called nflgame when you click a button but it just gives this error when you click the button

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Developer\workspace2\test2\main.py", line 16, in methods
for(y, t, w, h, a), info in schedule_games:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Here is the one and only class I have besides the GUI:

```
import sys
import nflgame
import nflgame.sched
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from window import Ui_Dialog

class Main(QtGui.QDialog):
  def __init__(self):
    QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
    self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.methods)

  def methods(self):
    schedule_games = nflgame.sched.games
    for(y, t, w, h, a), info in schedule_games:
        if y == 2013 and w == 17:
            print(' VS. ')

    team_home = h
    team_away = a
    home_game_scores_for = []
    away_game_scores_for = []
    home_game_scores_against = []
    away_game_scores_against = []

    gameHOME = nflgame.games_gen(2013, home=team_home, away=team_home, kind='REG')
    gameAWAY = nflgame.games_gen(2013, home=team_away, away=team_away, kind='REG')

    for g in gameHOME:
        if g.home == team_home:
                    home_game_scores_for.append(g.score_home)
                    home_game_scores_against.append(g.score_away)
        else:
                    home_game_scores_for.append(g.score_away)
                    home_game_scores_against.append(g.score_home)

    for g in gameAWAY:
        if g.home == team_away:
                    away_game_scores_for.append(g.score_home)
                    away_game_scores_against.append(g.score_away)
        else:
                    away_game_scores_for.append(g.score_away)
                    away_game_scores_against.append(g.score_home)

    self.ui.label.setText("AVG. Points Scored", team_home, round(sum(home_game_scores_for)/float(len(home_game_scores_for)), 1), "VS.", team_away, round(sum(away_game_scores_for)/float(len(away_game_scores_for)), 1))
    self.ui.label.setText("AVG. Points Allowed", team_home, round(sum(home_game_scores_against)/float(len(home_game_scores_against)), 1), " VS.", team_away, round(sum(away_game_scores_against)/float(len(away_game_scores_against)), 1))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
   window = Main()
   window.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: And what does the `nflgame.sched` module do?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are using the latest version of nflgame, but the documentation says that `nflgame.shed.games` is: "An ordered dict of schedule data, where games are ordered by the date
and time that they started. Keys in the dictionary are GSIS ids and
values are dictionaries with the following keys: week, month, year,
home, away, wday, gamekey, season_type, time.". See https://github.com/BurntSushi/nflgame/blob/master/nflgame/sched.py

Maybe that helps you?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the module you are using is [the one linked by @gurka](https://github.com/BurntSushi/nflgame/blob/master/nflgame/sched.py) , then `schedule_games` is a dictionary, so the loop should be (assuming Python 3.x, not 2.x):

```
for gsis_id, info in schedule_games.items():
    # info is itself a dict with keys: 
    #    week, month, year, home, away, wday, gamekey, season_type, time
    if info['year'] == 2013 and info['week'] == 17:
        print(' VS. ')
```

The docs don't say if the value of year is a string or a number, if former you will have to use `if int(info['year']) == 2013`.

Answer (score 0):

This error tells that your list's length differs from a suggested list of variables. Try to print the list before for loop and you will see what causes the error.

You need to put 
print(scheduled_games)
right before the for loop.